# Building 'Pong' with python (codeskulptor)

Tags: codeskulptor

I'm trying to build the arcade game 'Pong' in CodeSkulptor with Python. I need help with two things

1. Increase the ball velocity by 10% when it hits a paddle
2. Get a fix for the color buttons, which are not working

Here's the link to the code : http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_yJMm4nMju5X5zvk.py

```
# Implementation of classic arcade game Pong
import simplegui
import random

# initialize globals - pos and vel encode vertical info for paddles
WIDTH = 600
HEIGHT = 400       
BALL_RADIUS = 20
PAD_WIDTH = 8
PAD_HEIGHT = 80
HALF_PAD_WIDTH = PAD_WIDTH / 2
HALF_PAD_HEIGHT = PAD_HEIGHT / 2
LEFT = False
RIGHT = True
score1 = 0
score2 = 0

#paddle position
paddle1_pos = HEIGHT/2 
paddle2_pos = HEIGHT/2

#paddle velocity
paddle1_vel = 0
paddle2_vel = 0

# initialize ball_pos and ball_vel for new bal in middle of table
ball_pos = [WIDTH/2 , HEIGHT/2]
ball_vel = [0 , 0]

#set color theme
color_palette = ['#FF5252','#00BCD4','#536DFE','#8BC34A','#FFC107','#FF9800','#FF4081','#E040FB']

color = random.choice(color_palette)

def color_red():
    color = color_palette[0]

def color_l_blue():
    color = color_palette[1]

def color_d_blue():
    color = color_palette[2]

def color_green():
    color = color_palette[3]

def color_yellow():
    color = color_palette[4]

def color_orange():
    color = color_palette[5]

def color_pink():
    color = color_palette[6]

def color_purple():
    color = color_palette[7]

def open_game():
    global ball_pos, ball_vel
    ball_pos = [WIDTH/2 , HEIGHT/2]
    ball_vel[0] = 0
    ball_vel[1] = 0

# if direction is RIGHT, the ball's velocity is upper right, else upper left
def start_game(direction):
    global ball_pos, ball_vel
    ball_pos = [WIDTH/2 , HEIGHT/2]

    if direction == RIGHT:
        ball_vel[0] = random.randrange(120,240)/60.0
        ball_vel[1] = -random.randrange(60,180)/60.0

    if direction == LEFT:
        ball_vel[0] = -random.randrange(120,240)/60.0
        ball_vel[1] = -random.randrange(60,180)/60.0

# define event handlers
def new_game():
    global paddle1_pos, paddle2_pos, paddle1_vel, paddle2_vel
    global score1, score2  
    paddle1_pos = HEIGHT/2  
    paddle2_pos = HEIGHT/2 
    open_game()
    score1 = 0
    score2 = 0

def draw(canvas):
    global score1, score2, paddle1_pos, paddle2_pos, ball_pos, ball_vel
    global paddle1_vel, paddle2_vel, PAD_HEIGHT, PAD_WIDTH, BALL_RADIUS,HALF_PAD_HEIGHT, HALF_PAD_WIDTH
    global color_palette, color

    # draw mid line and gutters
    canvas.draw_line([WIDTH / 2, 0],[WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT], 1, "White")
    canvas.draw_line([PAD_WIDTH, 0],[PAD_WIDTH, HEIGHT], 1, "White")
    canvas.draw_line([WIDTH - PAD_WIDTH, 0],[WIDTH - PAD_WIDTH, HEIGHT], 1, "White")

    # update ball
    ball_pos[0] += ball_vel[0]
    ball_pos[1] += ball_vel[1]

    #ball with upper and lower wall collisions
    if ball_pos[1] <= BALL_RADIUS:
        ball_vel[0] = ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]
    if ball_pos[1] >= (HEIGHT-1)-BALL_RADIUS:
        ball_vel[0] = ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]

    #spawn ball left or right    
    if ball_pos[0] <= BALL_RADIUS+PAD_WIDTH:
        start_game(RIGHT)
        score2 += 1
    if ball_pos[0] >= (WIDTH-1)-PAD_WIDTH-BALL_RADIUS:
        start_game(LEFT)
        score1 += 1

    # draw ball
    canvas.draw_circle(ball_pos, BALL_RADIUS, 2, color, color)

    #keep paddle on the screen
    if paddle1_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT <= 0 and paddle1_vel < 0:
        paddle1_vel = 0
    if paddle2_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT <= 0 and paddle2_vel < 0:
        paddle2_vel = 0
    if paddle1_pos+HALF_PAD_HEIGHT >= HEIGHT and paddle1_vel > 0:
        paddle1_vel = 0
    if paddle2_pos+HALF_PAD_HEIGHT >= HEIGHT and paddle2_vel > 0:
        paddle2_vel = 0

    # update paddle's vertical position 
    paddle1_pos += paddle1_vel
    paddle2_pos += paddle2_vel

    # draw paddles
    canvas.draw_polygon([(0,paddle1_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT),(PAD_WIDTH,paddle1_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT),(PAD_WIDTH,paddle1_pos+HALF_PAD_HEIGHT),(0,paddle1_pos+HALF_PAD_HEIGHT)], 5, color, color)
    canvas.draw_polygon([(WIDTH,paddle2_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT),(WIDTH-PAD_WIDTH,paddle2_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT),(WIDTH-PAD_WIDTH,paddle2_pos+HALF_PAD_HEIGHT),(WIDTH,paddle2_pos+HALF_PAD_HEIGHT)], 5, color, color)

    # determine whether paddle and ball collide    
    if ball_pos[1] > paddle1_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT -2 and ball_pos[1]<paddle1_pos +HALF_PAD_HEIGHT +2 and ball_pos[0] - BALL_RADIUS <= PAD_WIDTH+2:
        ball_vel[0] = -ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1]

    if ball_pos[1] > paddle2_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT -2 and ball_pos[1] < paddle2_pos +HALF_PAD_HEIGHT+2 and WIDTH - (WIDTH - (ball_pos[0] + BALL_RADIUS)) >= (WIDTH - PAD_WIDTH) -2:
        ball_vel[0] = -ball_vel[0]
        ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1] 

    # draw scores
    canvas.draw_text(str(score1), (WIDTH/2 - 100,80), 60, color, 'sans-serif')
    canvas.draw_text(str(score2), (WIDTH/2 + 60,80), 60, color, 'sans-serif')

def keydown(key):
    global paddle1_vel, paddle2_vel
    if key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['w']:
        paddle1_vel = -4
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['s']:
        paddle1_vel = 4
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['up']:
        paddle2_vel = -4
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['down']:
        paddle2_vel = 4
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['space']:
        start_game(random.choice([LEFT,RIGHT]))

def keyup(key):
    global paddle1_vel, paddle2_vel
    if key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['w']:
        paddle1_vel = 0
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['s']:
        paddle1_vel = 0
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['up']:
        paddle2_vel = 0
    elif key == simplegui.KEY_MAP['down']:
        paddle2_vel = 0

# create frame
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Pong", WIDTH, HEIGHT)
frame.set_canvas_background('#192c36')
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)
frame.set_keydown_handler(keydown)
frame.set_keyup_handler(keyup)
frame.add_label('Start the game by pressing SPACE'),frame.add_label(' ')
frame.add_button('Restart', new_game, 100),frame.add_label(' ')
frame.add_label('Choose color theme: '),frame.add_label(' ')
frame.add_button('Red', color_red, 100)
frame.add_button('Light Blue', color_l_blue, 100)
frame.add_button('Dark Blue', color_d_blue, 100)
frame.add_button('Green', color_green, 100)
frame.add_button('Yellow', color_yellow, 100)
frame.add_button('Orange', color_orange, 100)
frame.add_button('Pink', color_pink, 100)
frame.add_button('Purple', color_purple, 100)


# start frame
open_game()
frame.start()
```

For the velocity I have no idea, I've tried different methods, none of them worked, but I'm pretty sure it's just some silly simple math

For the colors, the color variable is set to pick a random color from the list color_palette, but, other than that, the buttons are not doing what they are supposed to.

Comment: `ball_vel[0] = -1.1 * ball_vel[0]` ... and so on

Comment: where exactly do I add this piece of code because I tried this a couple of times and it was only giving me more errors ?

Comment: some body gave you very well documented code ... and a task to edit it ... if you are actually trying to learn then I suggest you read the whole code... where do you think you would put it? and if that doesnt work what errors do you get?

Comment: i added the code after each if statement in # determine whether paddle and ball collide. this doesn't give me an error but it simply breaks the whole block of code under that comment. so the ball just doesn't bounce off the paddles anymore

Comment: What are the number 2s in the collision code between ball and paddle for? codeskulptor.org/#user41_yJMm4nMju5X5zvk_0.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# determine whether paddle and ball collide    
if ball_pos[1] > paddle1_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT -2 and ball_pos[1]<paddle1_pos +HALF_PAD_HEIGHT +2 and ball_pos[0] - BALL_RADIUS <= PAD_WIDTH+2:
    ball_vel[0] = -1.1*ball_vel[0]
    ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1] # this line does absolutely nothing ...

if ball_pos[1] > paddle2_pos-HALF_PAD_HEIGHT -2 and ball_pos[1] < paddle2_pos +HALF_PAD_HEIGHT+2 and WIDTH - (WIDTH - (ball_pos[0] + BALL_RADIUS)) >= (WIDTH - PAD_WIDTH) -2:
    ball_vel[0] = -1.1*ball_vel[0]
    ball_vel[1] = ball_vel[1]  # this line does absolutely nothing ...
```

also your collisions are sort of broken ... it often times hits the paddle and mistakenly restarts the ball and scores a point ...

you need to add `global color` to the top of each of your color functions so that you assign to the global color instead of a local color ... there are many other ways to solve this ... but this will require the least amount of change and work

```
def color_red():
    global color
    color = color_palette[0]
```

Comment: i tried that too. it still doesn't work. same result as described in the comment above

Comment: no thats your collisions(you need to fix them ... even if you make no changes to your code it still glitches out and (incorrectly) restarts the ball regularly... by increasing the velocity you significantly increase the odds of this bug happening ) ... this is the answer to your question ...

Comment: okay I understand now. Thank you very much, any chance you could help with the collisions? it's a glitch i haven't been able to fix and i assumed it was just the computer

Comment: damn what a silly mistake. i should've figured this out myself. anyway, thanks for everything, i really appreciate it